# NFS default to 777

Tags: centos, php, nfs, file-sharing

I have an NFS share. This share is shared between several different applications. Our web server is running PHP and when it creates directories it is not setting the permissions correctly so it cannot write to the directory once created. How can I mount this NFS share to where PHP has full read/write access? Below is the directory that has been created along with the media server export options and the mount options on the web server. Ideally I could set the permissions on /opt/mount and whatever group/user is on that directory when I mount to that point the share assumes those permissions.

```
dr----x--t. 2 nobody nobody 4096 Jun  5  2014 user_2
```

Mount output:

```
media.dc1:/home/fs_share on /opt/mount type nfs (rw,vers=4,addr=10.10.20.127,clientaddr=10.10.20.42)
```

Exports file from media server:

```
/home/fs_share     10.10.20.0/255.255.255.0(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
```

Comment: The NFS share is not the issue, your problem is that files and directories created with php scripts have the wrong permissions! Default file permissions are typically the result of the umask environment variable, or possibly the result of your php code. Check and change one or the other or both.

Comment: I am doing a mkdir with permissions set to 0777. Like mkdir(/opt/mount/users,0777,true). The problem is it sets it to the lowest privilege. I don't quite understand the umask function.

Comment: You are correct thought. This isn't a NFS issue because I can create a directory and chmod it to 777 from the webserver. PHP just cannot do that. I am assuming because PHP is running as user php-fpm.

Answer (score 3):

You're using NFSv4. Too bad you did not specify your OS version, as it'll be rather important here.

Older versions of NFS used strictly UID/GID numbers, and so it was possible for the NFS server to be unaware of all the users and groups on the clients and vice versa - as long as the UID/GID numbers did not conflict, all was well.

But NFSv4 has the option of using *user/group names* instead of UID/GID numbers. If names are used, they are transmitted in form `user@domain`, where `domain` usually defaults to the DNS domain of each system, but can be changed to an arbitrary string if necessary. If the domain settings of the NFSv4 server and the NFSv4 client(s) won't match, or the user/group name mapping fails for any other reason, you're likely to see ownerships mapped to `nobody` and file permissions minimized - just like you're seeing.

In Linux, this user/group name mapping is done by the `rpc.idmapd` service. If this service is not running, that is also a possible cause for file ownerships getting mapped to `nobody`. In RHEL/CentOS/OEL 6.5 and older, this daemon should be running on both NFS clients and servers. (Yes, the client side has a `/usr/sbin/nfsidmap` upcall program that should make `rpc.idmapd` unnecessary on the NFS client side, starting from version 6.3... but it had a bug that was fixed only in RHEL/CentOS/OEL 6.6 and newer.)

In Linux, the NFS domain setting defaults to DNS domain name of the host, but it can be changed using the `Domain =` setting in `/etc/idmapd.conf` file. And in RHEL 6.3 and older, there was a bug that caused this setting to be ignored: if you're using NFSv4, you should upgrade to 6.4 or later. After changing the domain, you should run `nfsidmap -c` in 6.3 and newer; in older systems, you'll need to both restart the `rpc.idmapd` daemon and remount all NFS mounts.

---

If you wish to disable NFSv4's idmapping functionality and instead fall back to NFSv3-style use of UID/GID numbers only (which may be useful if your NFS server is e.g. a NAS box that has no information of user accounts on the client systems), you'll need to ensure that the `nfs` kernel module option `nfsv4_disable_idmapping` is enabled:

```
echo "options nfs nfs4_disable_idmapping=Y" >> /etc/modprobe.d/nfs.conf
```

This module option exists on RHEL 6.3 and newer, and should be enabled by default, but it's best to make sure.

On the server side, falling back to NFSv3-style UID/GID behavior on NFSv4 will require two things. First, a similar kernel option needs to be verified (or explicitly set) on `nfsd` kernel module:

```
echo "options nfsd nfs4_disable_idmapping=Y" >> /etc/modprobe.d/nfs.conf
```

Second, the security for the NFS export must be `sec=sys`.

Again, both of these settings should be the defaults on modern systems, but when working on older systems it'll be best to verify them.

On a NetApp NAS, the setting to enable the use of numeric UID/GID values on NFSv4 is either:

```
options nfs.v4.id.allow_numerics on
```

or:

```
cluster::> set diag
cluster::*> nfs server modify -vserver vs0 -v4-numeric-ids enabled
```

depending on NetApp version.

Answer (score 1):

The "umask" parameter in /home/user/.profile controls the permissions given to a file created by that user
Standart is umask=022 Which means 755 for files and 644 for directories.
If you want owner and group to have full permissions, then it should be "umask=002"

Answer (score 1):

This requires more complex permissions handling than UNIX permissions can handle effectively. filesystems ACLs are your solution here.

Using ACLs, you may inherit permissions from parent directories, as well as ownership. This will ensure that no matter who created files or directories in a particular subtree, they get their permissions from the parent directory (rather than a umask).

Investigate heavily the commands getfacl and setfacl. Using default ACLs, you can control this ownership and permissions inheritance.

This chapter of the RHEL storage admin guide is a very complete guide to ACLs, and it's a fairly definitive resource: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-acls.html

Answer (score 1):

If the PHP code can create the files, it sholud be able to "chmod" them.

```
<?php
chmod("/mydir/myfile", 0660);
?>
```

[Here](https://www.php.net/function.chmod) is the reference to the chmod PHP function.

If you want to mount the share with specific uid/gid (other tah nobody/nogroup), you could try exporting with all_squash

```
/export/myshare x.x.x.x(rw,all_squash,anonuid=<newUID>,anongid=<newGID>,sync)
```

From https://linux.die.net/man/5/exports:

> all_squash
>
> Map all uids and gids to the anonymous user. Useful for NFS-exported public FTP directories, news spool directories, etc. The
> opposite option is no_all_squash, which is the default setting.
>
> anonuid and anongid
>
> These options explicitly set the uid and gid of the anonymous account. This option is primarily useful for PC/NFS clients, where you
> might want all requests appear to be from one user. As an example,
> consider the export entry for /home/joe in the example section below,
> which maps all requests to uid 150 (which is supposedly that of user
> joe).